# Umbraco - How to import site images/aspx files easily like DotNetNuke?

Tags: image, content-management-system, upload, dotnetnuke, umbraco

I come from a DotNetNuke background. I have been able to get Umbraco to work, but I can only upload an image at a time etc. This is painfully slow because I have a large site. Other then using third party utilities is there anyway to speed up the upload process? Can I just drop the images in the media folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping the files in the media folder will have no effect as the Media library (in Umbraco) will not know that they are there.

The easiest route is to use the excellent [Desktop Media Uploader](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/desktop-media-uploader)